# Selecting and modifying a collection of elements using pure Javascript without looping

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I'm trying to select and style elements of the same style and/or class. So far I've found that doing so would require looping through the array of elements as so:

```
var examples = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

for (var i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
  examples[i].style.color = "cornflowerblue";
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to loop through these elements and individually select them by their index? I'm looking looking for the jQuery equivalent:

```
$(".example") // Chainable
```

**Example with a for-loop**

```js
var examples = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

for (var i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
  examples[i].style.color = "cornflowerblue";
}
```

```html
<p class="example">Example One</p>
<p>Example Two</p>
<p class="example">Example Three</p>
<p>Example Four</p>
```

Comment: I have to ask a very silly questions, but why don't you just use CSS? *.example{color: cornflowerblue}*. May be I din't understand the question correctly

Comment: 'standard' arrays have available the forEach method, allowing you to pass an array and a function that will be called for each of them. Unfortunately, the result returned from the getElements* and querySelector* functions are not arrays, but are of the type NodeList and therefore, do not have this method available.

Comment: @enhzflep So would my only viable option be to use the jQuery selector method instead?

Comment: @CarlEdwards - nope. See below for a jQuery-free solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array
  .apply([], document.getElementsByClassName("example"))
  .forEach(function (elmNode) {
    elmNode.style.color = "cornflowerblue";
  })
;
```

Comment: Whoever did the down vote might kindly justify ones opinion. Consequently the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245148/selecting-and-modifying-a-collection-of-elements-using-pure-javascript-without-l/30247817#30245516) of  [enhzflep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1630963/enhzflep) then deserves a down vote as well since it follows the same approach by using more code. On the other hand my proposed solution is as close to what the OP has asked for as it could be achieved under the given circumstances.

Comment: Everyone got an unexplained downvote, including @enhzflep - probably either someone messing, not getting it, or just validly exercising their right to vote however they choose. Annoying, but these things happen.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to notify a downvoter that you're appealing to them, and so SO is littered with "downvoter please explain" comments that were probably never even read by the downvoter. Anyway +1 for a useful suggestion, even though I would quibble with the "without looping" part of the question

Comment: @CupawnTae, thanks for the explanation. I carefully will read all the other (effected) answers and might feel free to vote on them or not.

Comment: Here the general attitude is that you're always free to vote on any answer for almost any reason - as I saw someone say "even if you don't like the font they used" - as long as you're not completely abusing the system. If you search for "downvote" on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ you'll find hours of endless discussion on the topic, including people suggesting that comments like "please explain downvote" should automatically be removed. Also, technically speaking, I shouldn't even be discussing this here either.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you would be able to use the `forEach` member function of arrays if it weren't for the fact that the return value from getElementsByClassName while behaving like an array, is actually a NodeList and does not have the `forEach` method built-in.

This is easily circumvented by writing a small function that will perform the looping and another that will perform the action on each element.

The following code will tackle the problem you present.

**1. The generic function**

```
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    for (var i=0, n=nodeList.length; i<n; i++) 
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
}
```

**2. The function for each of the elements**

```
function itemCallback(elem, index, list)
{
    elem.style.color = 'cornflourblue';
}
```

**3. Doing the actual job**

```
function changeExampleElemStyles()
{
    var examples = document.getElementsByClassName('example');
    forEachNode(examples, itemCallback);
}
```

Clearly, for a 'one-off' requirement to operate on a list of elements, this approach is overly verbose and would be better substituted with the code you've presented already.

In situations where this will need to be done frequently, this code cuts down on the amount of repetition and helps to make the code easier to read through quickly, while also preventing copy-paste errors or those otherwise introduced needlessly. You simply write function #2 for each of the tasks you need to perform on a list of elements, then obtain the list and get forEachNode to deal with the list using the function #2 that you wrote.

jQuery's always an option, naturally. Though it's fairly large overkill to include a 100kb library just for a few functions. :)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough run-down. For the `itemCallback` function what does the `list` parameter represent?

Comment: @CarlEdwards - that's okay. The `list` parameter refers to the entire list that contains the current element. I've not made use of this param (or the index) yet, but wrote the function so that it mirrored the `forEach` member of arrays. I guess you could count the number of items contained in the list in the callback function and do one thing if there was an even number of elements and another if there was an odd number. With the index, I suppose you could check remainder after dividing by 2 (i.e index % 2), which would allow you to do different things to alternate items in a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the same, but can achieve the same effect. You can dynamically add and modify a stylesheet element in the DOM:

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = ".example { color: cornflowerblue }";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

Then to change the colour to red later, just do:

```
sheet.innerHTML = ".example { color: red }";
```

More info at http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

**Updated snippet**

```js
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = ".example { color: cornflowerblue }";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

```html
<p class="example">Example One</p>
<p>Example Two</p>
<p class="example">Example Three</p>
<p>Example Four</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using CSS and JS. What you need to do is wrap your 'p' elements in another element (e.g div) and change class of the div in this case. In CSS you will have parent child css that changes style of your p elements.

```js
document.changeStyle = function () {
    document.getElementById("parent").className = "turnStyleOn";
}
```

```css
.turnStyleOn .example {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <p class="example">Example One</p>
    <p>Example Two</p>
    <p class="example">Example Three</p>
    <p>Example Four</p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Change Style" onclick="changeStyle();" />
```